# BULK add internal and guest users SharePoint groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, spo

I have a requirement to 're-provision' SharePoint access for migrated users. At the moment I have an extract of users and the sites/groups they have access to, some of these users are internal and some are guest/external.

Has anyone found a way to bulk grant access? 
For example, Ideally I'd like to input the below in to SPO PowerShell via .csv and the script will grant access to the correct group.

Joe.Bloggs@test.com, https://spo.sharepoint.com/sites/Test, Test Members

Grant.Access@test.com, https://spo.sharepoint.com/sites/DEV, Dev Visitors

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Csv file with header using below command and you will get array.

> [Import-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6)

You can loop this array and inside you can write below command.

> Add-SPOUser -Site
>   https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection -Group "Group
>   Name" -LoginName user@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com

I hope it will simplfy your work.

Use [this](http://3sharp.com/blog/use-powershell-to-automate-groups-and-users-provisioning-in-sharepoint-online/) example for reference.

Comment: Hi Anil,. thanks great! However I noticed that the Add-SPOUser command does not work for external users (i.e. adding a user with an external domain). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Moore, I am unsure that is there any such API is exposed by Microsoft. but you can use this link to bulk invite to external users. http://itgroove.net/mccalec/2016/01/19/sharepoint-online-invite-external-users-with-powershell/